# Export cells in column if another cell has a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

Try to make this make sense - 
Column J has email addresses, Column N is either Blank or numeric value.

I want to export the emails from Column J as well as the value from N to another column only if Column N is NOT blank.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your brief explanation, and assuming your values start in row 2. place this in row 2 of the column you wish to have the other two columns aggregate to and fill down.

`=if(N2<>"",J2&" "&N2,"")`

Comment: Thank you for that, that's really close! I really want like this - to export that data http://i.imgur.com/jdZ67rq.png